# What is the noise that the A320 makes on the ground?

Tags: aircraft-design, airbus-a320, airbus, noise, hydraulic-system

I've noticed that planes in the A320 family make a sawing noise on reaching the gate. The link below may give you an idea of what I mean (although the A320 in the video is still taxiing). Is this a hydraulic system or a pressure unit at work?

Comment: @mins The question you link to does not mention the PTU operation on the ground and the reason for it.

Comment: @mins But does not _ever_ mention that the whole point is single engine operation which is typical on ground. However, this question asks specifically for the barking while on ground. So maybe from the POV of a professional, things are clear, but to an enthusiast, the first question provides much better and clearer information.